# I am getting this error message while trying to use Testng in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng, heap-memory, stack-overflow

I am getting the error message such as stack overflow, heap memory error and similar messages after trying to use TestNG. And after installing TestNg the Eclipse feels heavy and became very slow to respond. and throwing this error message. [image]

Comment: I am using core 2 duo , 1.83 Ghz processor and 4 GB Ram. I reckon the ram might/processor might be an issue but don't know for sure.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

An error of such kind Stackoverflow and heap memory error occurs because of physical lack of resources such as lower Ram or slower processor. So the only solution to this was to allocate more memory to eclipse IDE. you can allocate more memory to eclipse by finding the eclipse.ini file in your directory where you have installed it. After finding the file, the file should be in notepad. open the file in  notepad and  edit the memory allocated. there are two things you need to change. Xms and XMX, which is minimum and max memory. I made mine from 256m to 512m for XMS and from 1024m to 2048M. But make sure  you allocate only the memory which is spare. otherwise your PC might crash. Hope this helps.